Flutter build apk always produces the same copy even after multiple builds and cleaning
I'm facing a very confusing issue with my Flutter project. Every time I run flutter build apk, it gives me the same APK as the first time I built it, even after making changes to the code. Interestingly, everything works fine when I run the app on the Android Studio emulator using adb. Here are the steps I've taken to try to resolve this issue:

Cleaned the project and cache:

./gradlew clean
./gradlew --stop
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk


Updated the Flutter version:

flutter upgrade


Verified my Flutter setup using flutter doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Linux Mint 21.3 6.8.0-35-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
• No issues found!


Tried to set versionCode and versionName from pubspec.yaml:

version: 1.0.1+5

Even after all these steps, I still get the same APK every time I build. The changes I make to the code do not reflect in the new builds.
Interestingly, while developing and run or reload in Android Studio emulator works fine.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any ideas on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Feel free to suggest any further steps or troubleshooting methods. Thank you!

After spending a considerable amount of time trying to resolve the issue, a fortunate mistake led me to send a copy of the application to a friend. He informed me that the application worked perfectly on his device, including the new features that were not functioning on mine. After some time and research, I began to suspect a caching issue. I then sent the copy with a new file name and through a different method, and it worked fine.
Afterward, I came across this post: Installing new version of Android app on a previous device always reverts to the old version. It describes the same issue I was experiencing, but I hadn't found it initially when I was dealing with the problem.
Thanks for your time.
